# Highstock: Remove the word "Zoom" from the rangeSelector

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to remove the word "Zoom" from the rangeSelector in HighStock? It's self-explanatory what the bar does, and the word takes up real estate that I could use to add another zoom option, like "1w" for one week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**use this it will work fine**

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang:{
    rangeSelectorZoom: ''
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following css

```
.highcharts-range-selector-buttons>text:first-child{
 display:none;
}
```

Here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/rh3c98my/1/)